# Does a 250MHz FIFO chip exist?

Tags: memory, high-frequency, fifo

If I have 8-bit parallel data being clocked out of a chip at 250MHz, is there some way I can buffer it? I only need to store about 1kB. Preferably this would be a FIFO. Does such a fast FIFO exist at a reasonable price (

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to implement that in a suitable FPGA, using the internal block RAM. Xilinx has this app note:

http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/white_papers/wp333.pdf

It could probably be implemented in a cheaper device, with more work.

Comment: So the memory would be inside the FPGA? Also, would it be possible if it was 32-bit data instead of 8-bit?

Comment: Yes, the memory is inside the FPGA. 32-bit data should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

Even on FPGA, 250MHz (2Gbps in this case) is a very hard task to achieve. Better tell us what's the application and why do You need such speeds? It would be easier to construct 32bit words by taking 4x 8bit and lowering the clock speed 4 times. This would guarantee possible Fmax at the same cost of the internal memory. Block RAM interface in FPGA can be even wider than 32bits (144bits afaik or so).

FPGAs are great for parallel data transfers: the more wide bus You have, the more data You can transfer, so better choose 32bit words instead of 8bit in internal conections.

Comment: It's for this: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/29316/crazy-homebrew-500mhz-1gs-s-oscilloscope-possible

Comment: Answered there.